# React - Rending JSON as UI objects and allowing any user changes to these UI objects to update the JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, data-binding, react-redux, 2-way-object-databinding

We have an internal tooling system that uses JSON to specify various actions, tasks etc. I'm making a single page web application to visualise this information. The web application contains a text area for editing/pasting JSON and another area which renders the JSON into UI elements.

So I want to take JSON from the text area and visualize it. But also, I want the user to be able to interact with this render visualization, making changes/configuring options and have it update the JSON immediately. I guess one could call that two-way binding.

While going from JSON -> HTML DOM elements is easy, I'm not sure how to do the reverse and go DOM -> JSON. Let's say we have some JSON

```
{"task1" : { 
  "canFail" : true, 
  "autoRestart" : false, 
  "connectionPropertys" : { 
    ... }
}
}
```

I would visualize task1 as some UI element with check boxes for canFail and autoRestart. I want the user to be able to both

1. edit the JSON "canFail" value to 'true' or 'false' and have that
   immediately render (this is easy - just re-render the entire JSON)
2. check or uncheck the canFail checkbox and have the JSON be
   automatically updated (hard part - where I'm stuck)

In React we pass state/properties down the the children, so the component rending the checkbox(es) would only know about canFail or autoRestart... it might not know about "task1". If the checkbox is changed, sure I can have some handler function fire, but it doesn't actually know what key/value in the JSON this corresponds to (e.g. it knows nothing of task1 and there could be multiple task1s).

Interested to know what a good approach would be here to tackle this. 
Thanks :)